# Qt QtConcurrent progressbar update

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtableview, qtconcurrent, qprogressbar

I have a `QTableView` connected to a `QAbstractTableModel`.
The model is used with `QtConcurrent::map` to make threads for the application (copying files)

I subclassed `QStyledItemDelegate` to display a `QStyleOptionProgressBar` in one of the tableviews cells, and the idea was to update the progress bar via the model. It works, but from 0 to 100% in one go, not smooth.

`QAbstractTableModel::setData()` is called in my "copy loop", but it seems that `QAbstractTableModel::dataChanged()`
is only emitted when the loops ends. No matter what I do.

This might be a wrong approach, but I have no clue how to access a given progress bar in the table view from a thread.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement setData() yourself in your table model class that is subclassing `QAbstractTableModel`. The base class implementation does nothing and returns `false`. You're responsible of emitting the `dataChanged()` signal if the data was successfully set.

Comment: I have done that already. The problem seems to be because setData() is called inside a loop. When the loop ends, the model is updated. I just need it to happen inside the loop.

Comment: You should look here (if it's still relevant), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230265/what-is-the-proper-way-to-set-qprogressbar-to-update-from-the-logic-layer